# printing multiple HTTP headers in Perl

Tags: perl, http

I am trying to run a legacy Perl web application based on TetraBB under Apache2 on Debian.

This application uses `print` to output HTTP headers, e.g. `print "Content-type: text/html\n";`.

However, it seems that after the first `print`, no further headers are accepted. In this example:
`print "A\n"; print "B\n"; print "\n";`, header `A` is recognized by the browser as a response header, while `B` ends up at the top of the response HTML.

Writing `print "A\nB\n\n";` works.

Also, if the first `print` does not contain `\n\n`, a `500 Internal Server Error` is generated.

What is causing this behavior and what can I do to make this work?

Comment: Because that's how HTTP headers work? You need a double newline in between the headers and the content.

Comment: @AKHolland That is what I am doing. Please read the question again carefully.

Comment: Then why are you sending the double newline after the first header?

Comment: @AKHolland I am not. I am sending a single newline after the first header (A) and a double newline after the second header (B).

Comment: Note that HTTP headers are supposed to be terminated/separated by a network newline, which unless you're on Windows where `\n` happens to be translated to a network newline by default handle layers, would be printed as `"\r\n"`.

Comment: Look at the [hack that CGI.pm has to do](https://metacpan.org/release/CGI/source/lib/CGI.pm#L182-195) for example.

Comment: @Grinnz In this case, I know that `\n` works, since `print "A\nB\n\n";` adds both HTTP header `A` and `B` as expected.

Comment: @Grinnz, Apache accepts LF from CGI scripts. It forms a correct HTTP response from these. As for the hack, I doubt the OP is using VMS or an EBCDIC machine

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference between

```
print "Content-Type: text/html\n";
print "Set-Cookie: ...\n";
print "\n";
```

and

```
print "Content-Type: text/html\nSet-Cookie: ...\n\n";
```

unless you changed something that specifically makes them different (e.g. [`$\`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$%5C)). In fact, if you haven't enabled auto-flushing for STDOUT, the output will accumulate in a buffer to be sent in 4 or 8 KiB chunks to the pipe. This means there's absolutely no detectable difference to the other end of the pipe either.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually outputting [CGI headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875), which the server then translates into response headers with the correct line endings. The CGI headers stop after the first double newline. Don't print two consecutive newlines until you are ready to terminate the headers, and do print them when you need to end the headers:

```
print <<HEADERS;
Content-type: text/plain
X-Some-Other: header

This is the body
HEADERS
```

Some servers have limits on the number of headers and on the length of header lines. Your error log may be able to say more about that.

To be any more useful than that, we need to see some actual code. A short program that demonstrates the problem would probably help you figure this out.

Comment: This is already what I am doing. The question is why it matters whether the header output is split over multiple print statements.

Comment: As I said, post a small demonstration program so we can see what you are actually doing.